# Displaying text onclicking href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I display a text in `<h3>` when clicking on a link.

I've tried this

html

```
 <a href="" data-text= "{{ x[2] }}"> 
    {{ x[0] }}
 <a>

<h3 id="title"></h3>

<textarea id="editText"></textarea>
```

script

```
  $("a[data-text]").click(function(){
    var value = "";
    $("#editText").val(value+$(this).attr("data-text"));
    return false;
  })
```

and it worked only for `textarea` but not for a `span` or `h3` tag.

Is there any work around? I would like to display values in the x[0] in the `h3` tag or at least be able to store it like the `data-text` and insert it in.

Comment: The same way you did with the `textarea`... But using `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it worked! Thanks a bunch!